# How to style Material-UI DatePicker header

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, nested, material-ui, styling

Material-UI DatePicker nests the text in the header at least 3 levels down in an h4 element (div => div => div =>button => span => h4):

```
<div class="MuiPickersStaticWrapper-staticWrapperRoot">
  <div class="MuiPickersBasePicker-container">
    <div
      class="
        MuiToolbar-root MuiToolbar-regular
        MuiPickersToolbar-toolbar
        MuiPickersDatePickerRoot-toolbar
        MuiToolbar-gutters
      "
    >
      ...

      <button
        class="
          MuiButtonBase-root
          MuiButton-root MuiButton-text
          MuiPickersToolbarButton-toolbarBtn
        "
        tabindex="0"
        type="button"
      >
        <span class="MuiButton-label"
          ><h4
            class="
              MuiTypography-root
              MuiPickersToolbarText-toolbarTxt
              MuiPickersToolbarText-toolbarBtnSelected
              MuiTypography-h4 MuiTypography-alignCenter
            "
          >
            Thu, Jul 15
          </h4></span
        ><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

      ...

</div>
```

I have tried every formatting option that I could find including className (makeStyles), classes, MakeTemplate etc., but I have been unable to format the text in the h4 element, e.g., fontSize.  Finally, I have resorted to disabling the header through a prop in the DatePicker component and building my own header.  Is there a method to format the h4 element?

Comment: Please give a codesandbox with your example.

Comment: Tried to put example on codesandbox but apparently does not support needed dependency: @material-ui/pickers.  Any suggestions?